# remove role id is member id discord py

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'll explain what my code does. It gets a member id and a role id. it should remove the role from the participant. but it doesn't do that. I made a mistake somewhere.

```
member = bot.get_user(int(memberid))
print(member)
role = bot.get_guild(2672867291227).get_role(int(roleid))
print(role)
await member.remove_roles(role)
```

AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bot.get_user` returns a `User` type. [A `User` type does not have the `remove_roles` method](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User), [however a `Member` type does](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member). You have to get the member from the guild, not the client. You can use the `get_member` method to get the member. So, this would be the ideal code:

```py
guild = bot.get_guild(2672867291227)
member = guild.get_member(int(memberid))
print(member)
role = guild.get_role(int(roleid))
print(role)
await member.remove_roles(role)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'get_member'

Comment: oh sorry ill improve the answer

Comment: I still get the error.. (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id' )
print(rolesid)
            print(type(rolesid))
            role = guild.get_role(rolesid)
_______________
800003388916891669
<class 'str'>
None